# How to partition hard disk for dual boot for Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux

Tags: windows-7, boot, filesystems, ubuntu-12.04

There are similar questions on this topic, but I could not find exact instructions for my case.

I want dual boot system that supports Windows 7 64 bit and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS OS. I want one partition to be shared between the two operating systems.

1. How many partitions do you recommend?
2. What kind of file systems should be used on each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows partition will be recognized by Ubuntu, so you don't have to create a separate partition to be shared between those systems.

You need at least 3 partitions:

- **NTFS** partition for Windows
- **ext4** partition for Ubutnu /root
- **swap area** for Ubutnu

IMPORTANT - First install Windows, THEN Ubuntu unless you want to configure `grub` by yourself